# goofy bash insertion using grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a `file.txt` that contains :

```
ab
cb
```

I want to find the `b` that is not proceeded by an `a`.

The following should [work](https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/32) :

```
grep -e "(?<!a)b" file.txt
```

But the instead it returns :

```
grep -e "(?<awk '1{ if(  NR % 2 == 0 && NR % 4 != 0) print }' ../../path/to/somedata.txt  | grep "A$" | wc -l)b" file.txt
```

Where the `awk '1{ if(  NR % 2 == 0 && NR % 4 != 0) print }' ../../path/to/somedata.txt  | grep "A$" | wc -l` is a previous command.

It seems that there was a substitution for `!`?  What is going on here and why won't my `grep -e "(?<!a)b" file.txt` work?

Comment: `!` is used for history substitution in interactive shells.

Comment: I'm not sure that extended grep supports negative lookbehind either. Perl regex should though.

Comment: so what would be the appropriate way to get it to work.   `grep -e "(?<\!a)b" file.txt` also fails

Comment: Use single quotes: `grep -e '(?<!a)b' file.txt`

Comment: I just wonder if `grep '[^a]b'` wouldn't be tons easier...

Comment: It would, but I need to use look around and this was the quickest and easiest mwe to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In interactive shells, `!` is used for [history substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction). You need to escape it with backslash or put it inside single quotes to prevent this. This shouldn't be an issue when you put your code into a script; history expansion is disabled by default in scripts.

Also, if you want to use PCRE features like lookbehind, you have to use the `-P` option to `grep` (assuming you're using GNU `grep`).

Answer (score 3):

Negative lookahead is only supported using `-P` (PCRE) option in `gnu-grep`. As [Barmar has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132471/548225) that you need to use `!` in single quotes to avoid `history` expansion.

However if you're using extended `grep` you can use this regex:

```
grep -E '(^|[^a])b' file
```

It will match any `b` that is either at line start or preceded by a `non-a` character.